# Matrices for change of basis linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the $\mathcal{B}$ matrix of the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by reflection through the $x_1 x_2$ plane for the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.

I understand the solution in general to be given by:

$$
 [~~[T(b_1)]_{\mathcal B} ~~~ [T(b_2)]_{\mathcal B} ~~~ [T(b_3)]_{\mathcal B}~~]
$$

However, since we are not changing bases from $\mathcal B$ my gut tells me that $T(b_k)$ is "already in the basis $\mathcal B $" and I shouldn't have to find it's coordinate mapping relative to $\mathcal B$ as shown in the matrix above.

That is, since I'm not changing bases, only applying a linear transformation,  my intuition says the answer would simply be:
$$
 [~~[T(b_1)] ~~~ [T(b_2)] ~~~ [T(b_3)]~~]
$$

By the "formula" this is incorrect, but can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  you are changing basis ... *twice!*

The transformation $T$ is described geometrically in terms of the standard basis $\mathcal{E} = \{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the matrix is

$$ \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} = \left[ \begin{array}{*{3}{c}} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{array} \right].$$

To obtain the matrix in $\mathcal{B}$-coordinates, you must *first* change basis to the standard coordinates, then apply the tranformation *there*, and finally change basis *back* to the new basis.  This is called conjugation (or a similarity transformation, as you likely know):

$$ \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} = \underset{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{E}}{\mathcal{P}} \; \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} \; \underset{\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{P}}$$

The trick is that when you write a vector $b_1$, you are implicitly expressing it *in terms of the standard basis*, so $b_1 = [\,b_1\,]_{\mathcal{E}}$, which is why the change-of-basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{E}$ is

$$\underset{\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{P}} = \big[ \big[\,b_1\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} \;\; \big[\,b_2\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} \;\; \big[\,b_3\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} \big] = \big[ b_1 \;\; b_2 \;\; b_3 \big].$$

Now, apply the matrix $T$ and give the result back in $\mathcal{B}$-coordinates, and you obtain

$$
\big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} = \big[ \big[\,T(b_1)\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} \;\; \big[\,T(b_2)\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} \;\; \big[\,T(b_3)\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} \big]
.$$

Comment: Thank you! Can you look at ex. 2 here: http://i.imgur.com/N7TD24K.jpg. The author jumped straight to computing the images of the basis vectors but here's what really happened. 
Let $\mathcal E$ be the standard isomorphism btwn $\mathbb P_2$ and $\mathbb R^n$ (correct?)
He computed $P_{\mathcal E \leftarrow \mathcal B}$ (which was $I_3$), applied the transformation in $\mathcal E$, then converted back to $\mathcal B$ by multiplying by $P^{-1}$ which is $I_3^{-1}$. Am I correct in saying this transformation just seems magical because $\mathcal B$ is essential the standard basis itself?

Comment: You have the right idea, essentially.  But notice that in this example, the transformation is first given $\mathbb{P}_2 \to \mathbb{P}_2$, and you are investigating what its matrix looks like in coordinates $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: That is an okay way to approach this problem, right? I just need to be careful what the questions are asking and translate from $\mathbb R^3 \to $\mathbb P_2$ when necessary.

Comment: I found your change of basis notes: https://catfiles.linfield.edu/People/Faculty/sblack/public/12-13/fall/250/change_of_basis.pdf helpful as well!