# Change of basis when given linear transformation in another basis

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344467/matrices-for-change-of-basis-linear-transformations).

I am studying conjugation/similarity transformations in my introductory linear algebra class. Here is an example:
$$ \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{B}} = \underset{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{E}}{\mathcal{P}} \; \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{E}} \; \underset{\mathcal{E} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{P}}$$

If I'm asked to find the $\mathcal D$ matrix for a linear transformation described in the basis $\mathcal C$ which acts on vectors whose coordinate mapping is relative to $\mathcal B$? Would that be in this form?
$$ \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{D}} = \underset{\mathcal{D} \leftarrow \mathcal{C}}{\mathcal{P}} \; \big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{C}} \; \underset{\mathcal{C} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{P}}$$

I don't think I can express this in the nice $PAP^{-1}$ form. What are the criteria for a transformation matrix to have this form?

Comment: I am confused, what have you done other than changed the names of $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I'm starting in one basis $\mathcal B$, and ending up in another, $\mathcal D$. Normally the linear transformation $T$ is given in terms of $\mathcal B$, where as here it's something different, $\mathcal C$. Would this still have the form [T(x)]$_{\mathcal D} = PAP^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, sure, I guess.  But what would be the point?  Why do we need $C$ in the second part?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Actually I'm nearly certain that  $\underset{\mathcal{D} \leftarrow \mathcal{C}}{\mathcal{P}}$ and $\underset{\mathcal{C} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}}{\mathcal{P}}$ aren't inverses. So then are you sure this can be expressed as $PAP^{-1}$?

Comment: They aren't inverses, so no they will not have that form. You can still find those matrices though.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber So then, how can we generalize? What conditions should be satisfied for the transformation to have $PAP^{-1}$ form?

Comment: @user1850672 Precisely that $\mathcal{D} = \mathcal{B}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to find $\big[\,T\,\big]_{\mathcal{D}} $ by defenision it should act on vectors whose coordinate mapping is relative to $D$ basis $\big[\,v\,\big]_{\mathcal{D}}$ and return $\big[\,T(v)\,\big]_{\mathcal{D}}$.